"Вероятнее всего" здесь вводное или не вводное?
"Если изменения возникают позже, то(,) вероятнее всего(,) только конкретная часть тела или орган подвергнутся изменениям".
Может ли "вероятнее всего" здесь выступать и как вводное, и как часть предложения?


Да, варианты возможны, так как здесь наречное выражение вероятнее всего сохраняет связь с глаголом: подвергнутся (как?) вероятнее всего, поэтому приходится делать выбор.

Но по структуре предложения, по общей расстановке знаков, а также с учетом медицинской тематики текста, можно использовать наречие без обособления:


Если изменения возникают позже, // то вероятнее всего только конкретная часть тела или орган / подвергнутся изменениям.
В то же время это авторский выбор.

Сравнить: Если изменения возникают позже, то, вероятнее всего, только конкретная часть тела или орган подвергнутся изменениям.

Как вариант, в таком предложении из-за скопления запятых хуже просматривается грамматика.
ПРИМЕРЫ
Предложения со словосочетанием ВЕРОЯТНЕЕ ВСЕГО
Конечно, если условия проживания меняются, то вероятнее всего необходимо приобрести новые знания по экономике или праву.
Предложения со словосочетанием ТО, ВЕРОЯТНЕЕ ВСЕГО
Если вы способны поддерживать это состояние, то, вероятнее всего, не будете испытывать диссоциацию и заново проживать событие.
Справочник по пунктуации
